# How to link 2 Excel files located in different PC's

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have one Excel file in my laptop and another in my desktop on the office of the work place.  How to connect them together?

Comment: Google Drive? Dropbox? MEGA? Any other online sync service?

Comment: Do I have to use sync service? can I connect them directly through the internet?

Comment: That's what a sync service is meant to do, in essence. Of course, you could probably set up a batch script that runs periodically, which checks, through SSH or something, which files is newer and replaces the older one with that. That would require both computers to be online, have the same script, and have port forwarding set up (not going to happen in an office) on both ends.

Comment: @Zacharee1 I think he means connecting values from one sheet into the other, not getting the same file in 2 different places synced.

Comment: does it change the whole file or just a cells?

Comment: My answer changes one cell. And it asks to sync this cell (renew its content) upon opening it.

Comment: would you mind to lead me how to do this?

Comment: See my answer. ;) Also, please place comments on it if things are unclear, because otherwise I don't get a notification.

Comment: I don't understand how to do it

Comment: Can you open the file from the other location?

Answer (score 1):

My company, [iPushPull](https://www.ipushpull.com/), has an Excel add-in that lets you share ranges of cells between desktop Excel spreadsheets running on different machines via our cloud service.

Once you have configured your source data sheet, whenever it updates, any linked sheets will also update live. You can also view the data on the web.

There is a free trial and a free tier for low usage so you can try it and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways this can be achieved.

If you use Remote Desktop to connect to your work pc from home, you can enable Remote Drive Mappings, so your local folders and files become available through virtual drives on the work pc.

Another option is to use VPN to connect the home pc to the work network and use the network to link the files.

Lastly, any other method of getting the files together can be used, such as bring it with you on a USB stick, email it, use something like dropbox etc.

Once this is established, open both workbooks on the same computer. From one workbook press the =, then click on the cell you want it to link to in the other sheet and press enter. A link has now been made.

Comment: does it change the Cells or the whole file?

Comment: This changes only an individual cell, and it is being updated every time you open the workbook, unless it cannot find the other workbook, then the old value remains.